# Getting Parent Object, from nested value

Tags: javascript, arrays, parent

what javascript code could you use to return person1 object providing id parameter 1 or person2 object providing id parameter 2?

```
  {
        person1: 
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'john'
        },
       person2: 
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'doe'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through them using foreach.. Lets say we had your object here:

```
var obj = {
  person1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
  },
  person2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'doe'
  }
}
```

Then you just loop and find the one.. so lets say you had the ID.

```
var ID = 2;
for (var i in obj) {
   if(obj[i].id == ID){
    result = obj[i]; //this is person2...
   }
}
```

I Hope this is what you are asking for.. your question wasnt very clear.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have `foreach`.

Comment: `obj` is an object, not an array, you can't use `obj.length` or `obj[i]`.

Comment: I meant it to become an object.... it has been a long time since i did javascript ok.. sometimes you mess up @Barmar

Comment: @LutforRahman actually if you see the edits i made on this anwser, i had previously had var on results.. results btw in this example is a global variable

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate through the properties of an object.

```
var obj = {
    person1: 
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'john'
    },
    person2: 
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'doe'
    }
};
var id_to_find = 1;
var name_found;
for (var name in obj) {
    if (obj[name].id == id_to_find) {
        name_found = name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Break...? In an if statement?

Comment: `break` is for the `for` loop.

Comment: That statement would give you. Error  obj is not defined (Javascript Version)

Comment: @Dsafds he is assuming `obj` has been previously defined

Comment: @Dsafds `obj` is the object in the question.

Comment: obj has never been defined anywhere in the question. so technically this is wrong.

Comment: It's just a placeholder, it doesn't matter for understanding the answer.

Comment: @Barmar this is a good answer, and it works, you should not be downvoted

Comment: shouldn't be, name_found = obj[name]? 

your code is returning "person2" instead of   {
        id: 2,
        name: 'doe'
    }

Comment: @LutforRahman The question says "return person1 from id(1)", so that's what I'm returning. If you wanted the whole object, you should have said that in the question.

Comment: ohh. my bad. My question was not clear. Your answer is correct on that scenario. thanks.